# How to push the value, based on matched value in PHP

Tags: php, php-7

```
$first = [
    ["class" => "1", "type" => "A"],
    ["class" => "2", "type" => "A"],
    ["class" => "3", "type" => "B"]
];

$second = [
    "1" => ["hobbies" => ["A" , "B"] ],
    "2" => ["hobbies" => ["A" ] ],
    "3" => ["hobbies" => [ "C" ] ]
];
```

Explanation

1. STEP 1 => `$first` array i am storing the class wise type like class
   1 having type A & class 2 having type is A & class 3 having type is
   B
2. STEP 2 => `$second` array keys i am storing class and values in
   hobbies
3. STEP 3 => `$second` array i want to push `type` from `$first` array
   based class what is type

I have written PHP code i got my expected results also, but i am two foraech then if condition, i think this is not the correct way to write. Is there any way to optimise my code?

My code

```
foreach ($second as $class => $value) {
    foreach ($first as $key => $temp) {
        if($class == $temp['class'] ){
            $second[$class]['Type'] = $temp['type'];
        }
    }
}
echo "<pre>";
print_r($second);exit;
```

My expected answer

```
Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [hobbies] => Array
                (
                    [0] => A
                    [1] => B
                )

            [Type] => A
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [hobbies] => Array
                (
                    [0] => A
                )

            [Type] => A
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [hobbies] => Array
                (
                    [0] => C
                )

            [Type] => B
        )

)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As keys in `$second` are the same as `class` in `$first` you can do this:

```
foreach ($first as $item) {
    // check if there's a key `$item['class']` in `$second`:
    if (isset($second[$item['class']])) {
        $second[$item['class']]['type'] = $item['type'];
    }
}
```

This code will use only one `foreach` over `$first` array.